# Entities Randomly Becoming Invisible in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods, minecraft-spigot

I'm running a Spigot 1.11.2 server and randomly I will often have mobs, dropped items and most entities in general become invisible. This is particularly irritating because creepers can sneak up on me and I can't see them. I've searched online to find people with similar problems but I haven't found anything. I am using the Optifine mod and I don't think that has anything to do with it but I'm not sure. Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this problem persist when you use a Vanilla version?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a known bug/issue that affects Minecraft versions 1.8+, and has been reported to Mojang: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-65040

Answer (score 0):

It may be your internet connection. You said it was a server, and mods disappearing constantly is a normal issue, especially if you're the one running it/ a pc with bad connection runs it. Try it out.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. My connection to the server is great and my internet speed is faster than most people have. The server isn't lagging either, it runs fairly well. I'm not experiencing any sort of lag, just this bizarre problem where mobs and other entities randomly become invisible and I have to reconnect for them to show up.